# Running Systemd in Docker for Ubuntu 16.04, for Ubuntu 18.04 it works

Tags: docker, ubuntu, systemd, molecule

for a molecule test I am trying to run the command "localectl status" in a role task.

With the following settings in the molecule.yml it works for Ubuntu 18.04. but not for 16.04., in 16.04. the error "Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory" is returned.

Here is the molecule.yml under the platform image:

```
command: /sbin/init
capabilities:
  - SYS_ADMIN
tmpfs:
  - /run
  - /run/lock
  - /tmp
volumes:
  - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
```

Thank you for your help!